# How can I read multiple images in the below script?

Tags: python, image, opencv

```
cv2_imshow((predict[0].masks.masks[0].numpy() * 255).astype("uint8"))
```

In this script I can to read one image but how can reed multiple images in predict[]?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

is predict a list of objects? if so, does this help?

```
import cv2

# Loop over all the masks in predict
for mask in predict:
    # Display the mask for the first object in the list
    cv2.imshow('Mask', (mask.masks.masks[0].numpy() * 255).astype("uint8"))
    cv2.waitKey(0)

# Close all windows when done
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: import cv2

# Loop over all the masks in predict
for mask in predict:
    # Display the mask for the first object in the list
    cv2_imshow((mask.masks.masks[0].numpy() * 255).astype("uint8"))
    cv2.waitKey(0)

# Close all windows when done
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Comment: after two trials it says "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'masks'"  what could be the reason?

Comment: can you share predict variable?

Comment: the variable as I wrote above is mask

Comment: import cv2

# Loop over all the masks in predict
for mask in predict:
    # Display the mask for the first object in the list
    cv2_imshow((mask.masks.masks[0].numpy() * 255).astype("uint8"))
    cv2.waitKey(0)

# Close all windows when done
cv2.destroyAllWindows()